# How to impelement acm portal ciration style?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Please visit this page :

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1531914.1531927&coll=DL&dl=ACM&CFID=34528024&CFTOKEN=57549708

there is a 'Export Formats' section in the right column. a window opens by clicking on each format. There are tab-like links in the opened window.

I need to implement like this in my site. I think maybe i can use jquery ui tabs and dialog for doing it. but i am not sure.

what is your suggestion ? is it a good way for doing this mission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes jQuery UI is definitely the way to go.